# How to return an object from C that contains a numpy array using ctypes interface?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Apologies if this is pretty basic, I'm pretty new to ctypes/python.

My goal is to have a call to a C-library that generates an object containing a (dynamically-allocated) array, then return this object to python and save it in a python data structure (for the example here, an object that includes a numpy array of ints). Here's what I have so far:

C-library relevant code:

```
struct footype{
   int p1;
   int *myarr;
}
footype myfun(int nx, ny, nz){
  static footype myfoo; 
  myfoo.myarr = new int[nx*ny*nz];
  myfoo.p1 = nx+ny;
  return myfoo;
}
```

And the relevant python code:

```
import numpy as np
from ctypes import *
class Foopy(Structure):
  _fields_ = [("p1",c_int),("mat",POINTER(c_int))]
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libmyfun.so")
lib.myfun.restype = Foo
myfoo = lib.myfun(10,10,10)
myobj.arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(myfoo.mat,(10,10,10))
myobj.p1 = myfoo.p1
```

This nominally works in that `myobj` has the expected content. But I'm wondering if this is asking for trouble, since from the numpy.ctypeslib.as_array doc: "The numpy array shares the memory with the ctypes object." - which in my case contains a pointer, and I'm not clear where that memory is owned/managed.

I guess my question is - is there a better/more generic way to do this? As a corollary, how would this work without the magic of ctypeslib.as_array if instead the returned object contained a dynamically-allocated array of some other objects, and the goal was to capture it to a python list?

Comment: There is no language C/C++!

Comment: Edited to fix that, but it doesn't change much :)

Comment: In the code? No In yourr mind? Hopefully :-)